# Any differences between iterating over values in columns of dataframe and assigning variable to data in column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I ran the following codes but Spyder returned "float division by zero"

```
import pandas as pd
file = pd.read_csv(r"data_ET.csv")

def normalise(df, columnName):
    for value in df[columnName]:
        df[columnName] = (value - df[columnName].min())/(df[columnName].max()-df[columnName].min()) (This line showed up error)
    return df[columnName]
#b)
normalised_RTfirstpass = normalise(file, 'RTfirstpass')
normalised_logfreq = normalise(file, 'log_freq')
file['normalised RTfirstpass'] = normalised_RTfirstpass
file['normalised logfreq'] = normalised_logfreq
print(file)
```

When I changed into this, it works (the change here is assigning column values to a variable)

```
import pandas as pd
file = pd.read_csv(r"data_ET.csv")

def normalise(df, columnName):
    value=df[columnName]
    df[columnName] = (value - df[columnName].min())/(df[columnName].max()-df[columnName].min())
    return df[columnName]
#b)
normalised_RTfirstpass = normalise(file, 'RTfirstpass')
normalised_logfreq = normalise(file, 'log_freq')
file['normalised RTfirstpass'] = normalised_RTfirstpass
file['normalised logfreq'] = normalised_logfreq
print(file)
```

Can anybody explain why the later works but the former does not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

df[Columnname] returns a pd.Series object and you are trying cast a Series object into int.
while in latter case, value=df[ColumnName], df[ColumnName]-df[ColumnName].min()/(....),
the pandas will broadcast the df[ColumnName].min() (which is a int/float value) into a pd.Series object. pandas automatically performs matrix operation on dataframe, thats why you do not need to iterate for every value in column.

Comment: From your answer, I understand that Python shows error with the line: df[columnName][idx]-df[columnName].min(), because df[columnName][idx] is individual value (index assigned so it is individual value), while df[columnName].min() performs as pd.series object, so the subtraction here does not work well right?

Comment: df[ColName].min() itself returns an individual value. The operation with df[ColName] is what makes it to broadcast into same shape pd.Series object. Also, the indexing does not occur the way you mentioned, you need to use .iloc or .loc method for it.